# Use of $_SERVER variables in custom plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, plugin, server

In my Joomla application, I have functionality where I use server variables, like request_uri and query parameters for parsing url string.

This function is used in many modules. So, I wanted to implement the same functionality by using a custom plugin, following [Joomla](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.5:Creating_a_content_plugin#onContentPrepare) tutorial.

My question is whether using a plugin in this case is appropriate.
And can we use server objects in a plugin class?

If yes, how to use this plugin in my other modules and components.

Any detailed answers are appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail regarding how your modules will use the gathered information?  Also, if you're simply grabbing URL query parameters there's a much, much, much simpler way using Joomla core.

Answer (score 3):

You could create your [**own library**](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_own_library_in_your_extensions) with the functionality you want to re-use in all your extensions and load it each time with [**JLoader**](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JLoader.html).

The **`$_SERVER`** is a SUPERGLOBAL variable and can be accessed anytime from everywhere.

Since you are working with Joomla, you may want to use what Joomla has to offer, so have a look at [**JURI**](https://docs.joomla.org/Category:JURI)

Job could be done with a plugin as well. For example you could create a system plugin and in your plugin's classes create public methods.

Accessing your plugin from your modules:

```
$myPluginFramework = new MyPluginFramework();

$myPluginFramework->myRequestUri();
```

Note that the plugin must be enabled in order to be able to create a new object of your plugin class. You probably have to consider any checks for if the class exists

```
if (class_exists('MyPluginFramework')) {
    $myPluginFramework = new MyPluginFramework();
    $myPluginFramework->myRequestUri();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is it necessarily be a system plugin? Or can i use a content plugin with an event like on content prepare

Comment: @user168983: I don't see how the onContentPrepare would be useful in your case, and generally a system plugin sounds a better fit in the context of your needs. Again, I think it could be better if you simply create your own lib (framework) and use it in your extensions as and when needed.